# Does adb root command survive reboots?

Tags: linux, adb, root-access

I am little confused by the behavior of my device recently. I tried to push a file into my unrooted device and it did throw "Permission denied on me". i did `adb root` and then tried to push the file and it seemed to be working fine.

Now, when I rebooted the device, I thought that until and unless I do `adb root` again, I will be seeing permission denied error. But somehow, but my push command was successful this time.

- Does it mean that root command survives the reboots?
- If yes, how can I take it back to the state when it was not allowing me to push the files.

I am doing this becuase I am trying to understand the behavior of a device without root access when I automate some commands and unpredictable behavior of my device actually has confused me at this point.

Comment: To which location in the device you tried to push ?

Comment: /data/data/com.android.gallery3d/shared_prefs/com.android.gallery3d_preferences_camera.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, ADB root does not survive reboots (thankfully, that would be a nice security hole...)
In your case, I'd guess that the permissions on that file got changed, allowing you to push it the second time.